# Special trimaran design for extra power

Tags: boats, sailing

First time posting on this particular forum so the usual about directing me to another stack exchange if applicable. I found most related questions to boats here, so I hope I'm at the right place.

I'm looking into the design of a big, big sailing boat for the open ocean. The idea is to give it as much **power** as possible (not necessarily speed). Right now I'm looking at the design of the hull. Boats lose power to the water thanks to friction. A catamaran or trimaran will perform much better to reduce this friction than a mono-hull. As I understand it, both by raising the boat higher out of the water and with less material facing the water head on even if it is the same depth of a mono-hull. It has the added benefit of reducing the heeling of the boat, giving more power to the sails.

Because of the weight of the sails, it is near certainly better to have a trimaran than a catamaran. In addition, trimarans heel over even less than catamarans.

The friction will be from wave drag, direct drag and skin drag. Obviously a trimaran has much more skin drag than the others, but compensates with the ability to float higher in the water. Now for the question.

[image: 1. Mono-hull 2. trimaran 3. trimaran special]

I want to determine if the special trimaran, the 3rd option, is better than the second more normal trimaran in raw power. Because the boat is really big, it can make sense to further reduce weight and skin friction by making individual pontoons that are connected with a minimal skeleton of sturdy materials. It does increase direct drag and possibly wave drag, and the reduction in weight might not be offset by a possible lesser ability to stay afloat, making the boat go deeper into the water.

In the design the side pontoons are a bit behind to allow the wave of the middle one to pass, but I'm not sure if this has enough advantages. Otherwise they are all equally long.

The boat is about 200m (656foot) long and between 40 and 50m (131 to 164 foot) wide. The length is mostly fixed for the easiest reference, while the width can still be adjusted for a better performance.

Does the nr 3 special trimaran outperform the nr 2 trimaran in power?

Handholds to calculate this myself are also appreciated, and if there is simply a better design as well.

Comment: Consider that hull length is key to reducing drag.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on [engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I can migrate it to Engineering for you. Not sure how it will be received there.

Comment: @Willeke♦ it would be appreciated. If it isn't ok there, I'll move or remove it there.

Comment: Power is a function of the sails, not the hull. In terms of your ships, 1 has the highest cargo capacity, 2 is the fastest, 3 would probably be both the slowest and have least cargo capacity. Hull speed is a function of length.